# Color the bars using Angular-Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using the following code-

HTML-->

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="chartCtrl">
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-colors= "colors" >
</canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

JS-->

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("chartCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  $scope.series = ['Series A'];

  $scope.data = [
    [0, 29, 40, 56, 56, 55, 40]
  ];

  $scope.colors = [{
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(207,54,54)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(207,54,54)'
  }];

});
```

I'm not able to get the bars in a different color (like Red). I read similar posts on Stack Overflow and used something like-

```
chart-colors = " [{
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
    }]"
```

but the bars are still in the same (default) light blue color.
Am I referring the colors wrong in the canvas tag ?

Comment: Ok so I'm not sure why the documentation says to use chart-color. I used something like $scope.colours = ['#ff0000']; in the JS, and then chart-colours="colours" in HTML and it worked. (Note: I'm still using "colours" and not "colors", and that is how it worked)

Comment: Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
  $scope.data = [
    [0, 29, 40, 56, 56, 55, 40]
  ];
```

Use this

```
  $scope.data = 
    [0, 29, 40, 56, 56, 55, 40]
  ;
```

This will give you something like this.

[image: Bar]